# problems with a switch statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

i am to make a web-app that shows a music video. i created some html with a video, a playbutton, a canvas where i show some audio-bars and some Headings named "intro", "verse" and "guitar solo".

I want to switch between the headings when the song goes from one section to another. however my switch statement doesn't seem to work. i get an error in line 49.

My Javascript looks like this.

I'd appreciate any input on what i might do wrong :)

```
var video = 5;
var analyser;var canvas;
var time;

$(function() {
    video = $("video")[0];
    $("body").on("click", "#playbutton", startStopVideo);

    createAudioAnalyser();
});



function createAudioAnalyser() {
    context = new webkitAudioContext();
    analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    canvas = $('#soundwave')[0]; 
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    source = context.createMediaElementSource(video); 
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
}

function soundAnimation() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(soundAnimation); 
    analyser.fftSize = 128;
    fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,90,255,0.3)'; 
    bars = 120;
    for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
        bar_x = i * 3;
        bar_width = 2;
        bar_height = -(fbc_array[i]);

        ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
    }
}

//this thing gives an error
setInterval(function() {
    myVid = document.getElementById("video");
    time = parseInt(myVid.currentTime,10);
    switch(time) {
        case 2
            $("#intro").switchClass("activebox", "inactivebox");  // Here's the error... what is it?
        break;
    }
},1000);
//---------

function startStopVideo() {

    if(video.paused) {
        video.play();
        soundAnimation();
    } else {
        video.pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: Telling us the error would be very useful (for not just us, but for you).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Whenever you use phrases like "I get an error", take that as your prompt to immediately tell us *what that error is*. It will drastically increase the likelihood of us being able to help, since we can immediately focus on how to fix what's wrong rather than having to first figure out what *is* wrong.

Comment: You missed a colon (`:`) in your `case` statement. (See my answer)

Answer (score 4):

Typo:

```
case 2
```

Should be:

```
case 2:
//    ^ You missed that.
```